# Using mod_rewrite for user pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So for now, when you use my search function to search a user and go to their page, you will get something like this. "http://www.mywebsite.com/profile/?pid=username"

The php on that page then gets the GET variable, and runs a query to get all of the information needed.

I would love to get rid of the ?pid= part and have just "http://www.mywebsite.com/profile/username"

But I am having trouble understanding any of the results I get with google on this specific URL. Most examples involve PHP files, which I'm using wordpress and embedding my php via execphp.

Comment: There are about 563946392856 examples for this alone here on StackOverflow. None of that helped in your attempts? You should first try yourself, if you fail (which is fine!) then search and understand your finds, if that is not enough (which is fine!) then post a question here, but _include your attempts so taht we can see where you are standing_.

Comment: Actually @arkascha, there are only [9,582,793 questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/313986/total-bad-questions-good-questions-and-total-questions#resultSets) on stackoverflow as of this post.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you in a `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/profile/([^/]*)$ /profile/?pid=$1 [L]
```

Comment: `<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/profile/?pid=<?php echo $results['user']; ?>"</a>` Is the link in which you would click to get to the page. It still displays the `?pid` part using what you provided. Question is, is this link correct?

Comment: After you implement the `.htaccess` file, you would rewrite it to: `<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/profile/<?php echo $results['user']; ?>`

Comment: Doing so just sends me to the page not found part of the site. So it's still requiring that I send a get variable.

Comment: Then, you're most likely implementing the `.htaccess` file incorrectly, or your host does not support `.htaccess` (Perhaps it's not apache?). Do some google searches, implement basic .htaccess functionality to make sure it's even working, and then you can diagnose my problem.

Comment: It's godaddy, all of that comes default. Again I know this question is all over, but it seems to be something I am missing. And maybe it is due to this code here

`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

This is the .htaccess file in the root directory. I've tried implementing your method several different ways. DO I need to make new conditions?